# Apply Css Class To Rad Grid From C# Code Behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, radgrid, radgridview

I have a css class set-up like so:

```
.cellOneCellPadding {
    padding-left: 9pt !important;
}
```

Now I am attempting to add the padding to a RadGrid from the C# code behind like this

```
foreach (GridDataItem row in r.MasterTableView.Items)
{
    row["MainData"].CssClass = "cellOneCellPadding";
}
```

However, the - 9pt padding on the left is not applied, nor do I get an error.  What would be the appropriate way to apply the 9pt padding to one column only of a radgrid?

**EDIT**
I have also tried

```
row["MainData"].Style.Add("padding-left", "9pt !important");
row["MainData"].Attributes.Add("padding-left", "9pt !important");
```

Comment: CSS is usually case sensitive. So you should use `row["MainData"].CssClass = "cellOneCellPadding";`

Comment: @VDWWD - good catch.  I copy/paste the css classname into the C# code behind and still not being applied

Comment: If `row` is the same in HTML as an `<tr>` then you need to specify the `td` in the css: `.cellOneCellPadding td {` or specify a cell in that row: `row["MainData"].cell["myCell"]`.

Comment: @VDWWD - see my edit.  Am I doing the same thing looping the rows in my foreach loop?

Comment: Try `.cellOneCellPadding TD { padding-left: 9pt !important; }`. (I'm not familiar with RadGrid so i cannot say your loop is correct)

Comment: @VDWWD - try that in the C# or in the css

Comment: In the CSS file.

Comment: @VDWWD - no such luck.  I also have tried the two things I added in my edit to no avail

Comment: Inspect the _rendered_ html visually (view source), combined with standard browser dev tools inspection. You'll likely find your answer.

Comment: @EdSF - I found the answer from much googling.  It is that this product does not render css classes assigned to a pdf.  If I was trying to apply the css class for rendering on page it would be successful, but not for the export to pdf function.